# Fluid, Css, Hover Box Shadow

Tags: hover, outer-join, fluid, box-shadow, glow

I am new to stackoverflow, just joined. I am pulling my hair out, please help.

http://tygoro.com/landing/

This box + triangle I want to have a box shadow on HOVER. Plus I want it to be fluid if possible! I am not sure how to accomplish this, I am looking for a master. The hover color would be blue. Just a light "outer glow" or box-shadow + blur. As soon as I go to use % instead of pixels, it is all gone.

this is the desired before/after effect i would to achieve with css, possible??

https://secure.static.tumblr.com/889a971e1e2d2e42bf1da266dc334a9b/qkyuuug/iIrncjg2i/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_6wkq4a95vw8w4o808w0o8wg0o_640.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
.generate-inside-page-header-content:hover .arrow-line,
.generate-inside-page-header-content:hover  .arrow-down,
.generate-inside-page-header-content:hover  .oval-left,
.generate-inside-page-header-content:hover  .oval-right{
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #0099FF;
}
```

are you need that?